# Unable to start ejabberd using ejabberd_app:start(normal,[])

Tags: openssl, erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I'm trying to start ejabberd from erlang shell using ejabberd_app:start(normal,[]).

but i'm getting the error

[image]

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 .

The ejabberd version is 19.02 .

From the error above, i can understand that; all the dependencies using `fast_tls` could not be start due to the error

> "'Failed to load NIF library: '$HOME/ejabberd-19.02/deps/fast_tls/priv/lib/fast_tls.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_ssl'"}],[]} .

I don't understand that error .

But my google searches made me to understand that it is related to openssl.

I installed the latest version of openssl, but nothing changed.

Please can someone help me to solve this problem .

Comment: If you run `ldd $HOME/ejabberd-19.02/deps/fast_tls/priv/lib/fast_tls.so` in the terminal, what does it print? Seems like the TLS driver is not finding the OpenSSL dynamic library for some reason...

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffecb1a0000)
 libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1f3adc7000)
 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1f3a984000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1f3a593000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1f3a38f000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1f3b238000)

Comment: that is the output

Comment: Right, so it is able to find the OpenSSL library. Perhaps there is a version incompatibility. How did you install ejabberd? Did you build it from source, or use a binary package?

Comment: i built from source

Comment: So that's strange, because if you build from source I would expect it to find the right version of OpenSSL... Not sure what's going wrong, to be honest

Comment: hemm bad for me .

Comment: i think i will turn toward the binary file

Comment: Why you do not start application in OTP standard way: application:start(ejabberd_app). ?

Comment: i don't think it's going to change anything because even when i   sudo make install , i get the same issue